Electric field in the plane of a charged ring
It's basically this question Electric field off axis inside a charged ring., but I want to know if it is possible to solve this integral analitically.
\begin{align}
E= \dfrac{k\lambda}{R}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{\cos\theta-a}{\left(1+a^2-2a\cos\theta\right)^{3/2}}d\theta}_{I}
\end{align}
I was thinking that complex analysis might help. What I tried:
With:
\begin{align}
z=e^{i\theta};\ \ \ \ \ \ dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta=izd\theta; \ \ \ \ \ \ d\theta=\dfrac{dz}{iz}
\end{align}
and using the well-known identity:
\begin{align}
\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\dfrac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}
\end{align}
The integral becomes:
\begin{align}
I=\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\dfrac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}-a}{\left(1+a^2-2a\dfrac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}\right)^{3/2}}\dfrac{dz}{iz}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
I=\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\dfrac{z^2-2az+1}{2z}}{\left(1+a^2-az-\frac{a}{z}\right)^{3/2}}\dfrac{dz}{iz}
\end{align}
I was thinking about residue theorem, but the problem is the power of the denominator. I understand that here we do not talk about poles, but rather about branch points. Here I am stuck.

The result can be expressed in terms of complete elliptic integrals as noted here.

In order to apply the Residue Theorem you must take into account a branch-cut in the denominator due to the presence of the $\displaystyle 3/2$-power.

$$I=\frac{-2\left(a+1\right)\cdot \mathrm{E}! \left(\frac{2 \mathrm{\sqrt{a}}}{a+1}\right)-2(a-1)\cdot \mathrm{K}! \left(\frac{2 \mathrm{\sqrt{a}}}{a+1}\right)}{a(a^{2}-1)}$$

Calling your integral $\operatorname{I}\left(a\right)$, you may recognize that its integrand is simply the derivative :
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{da}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2a\cos\left(\theta\right) + a^2}}\right]
\end{equation}
But this is the Generating Function of the Legendre Polynomials:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -2a\cos\left(\theta\right) + a^{2}}} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\operatorname{P}_{\ell}\left(cos\left(\theta\right)\right)
\,a^{\ell}
\end{equation}
To proceed you may use the Bonnet Recursion Formula for Legendre Polynomials and obtain your solution as an infinite series.

To put this into the physics context, it's easier to work with the electric potential than the electric field here. (Indeed, this expansion amounts to the usual multipole expansion for the electric potential $1/|x-x'|$.)

Thanks! I have question (sorry if it's a stupid one, I am not a mathematician). Given that it is an infinite sum, would this work similar to a Taylor expansion, in the sense that the more terms you add, the closer you are to the actual solution? So keeping only the first $n$ terms, would actually be an approximation?
